# Search for a part of a string in a file in shell

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a file with a list of names in it. I am trying to search for names with a certain group of strings and print them to a new file in shell. Can you please help?

Here's what I am looking at.
Text file(names.txt) contains names like

```
New York_USA
Delhi
Moscow
Tokyo
Austin_USA
Beijing
Chicago_USA
```

I am trying to get the names with _USA in a seperate file.
Here's what I have tried

```
#/bin/ksh
for city in "cat names.txt"
do
if ["$city" =~ "*_USA"]
then
echo "$city in USA" > USAnames.txt
fi
done
```

Comment: Why don't you simply `grep _USA names.txt`? Or `sed -n 's/_USA$/& in USA/p' names.txt` if you really insist on reformatting the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to execute the `cat` command instead of quoting it, fix your test operator ([ --> [[), and append >> instead of overwrite >, and write a regex instead of a glob pattern:

```
#/bin/ksh
for city in `cat names.txt`  # notice the back quotes
do
if [[ "$city" =~ .*_USA ]]
then
echo "$city in USA" >> USAnames.txt
fi
done
```

A more idiomatic way would perhaps be:

```
#/bin/ksh
while read city 
do
if [[ "$city" =~ .*_USA ]]
then
echo "$city in USA" >> USAnames.txt
fi
done < names.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i tried it this way. I don't get any output at all. I supposed the if condition is not well defined. is there any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: I made some edits to the code, check again, it should work now. You had multiple problems there...

Comment: Ok, fixed one last problem: there should be no quotes around the patter in the if condition

Comment: And as tripleee says in the comment, there are simpler ways to achieve what you want if that's all you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` or `sed` will be easier

if you want the output to be like this

```
New York_USA in USA
Austin_USA in USA
Chicago_USA in USA
```

use

```
awk '/_USA$/ {print $0, "in USA"}' names.txt > USAnames.txt
```

or `sed`

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\)_USA$/\0 in USA/p' names.txt > USAnames.txt
```

or if you want output to be

```
New York in USA
Austin in USA
Chicago in USA
```

use

```
awk -F_ '/_USA$/ {print $1,"in USA"}' names.txt > USAnames.txt
```

or `sed`

```
sed -n 's/\(.*\)_USA$/\1 in USA/p' names.txt > USAnames.txt
```

**Edit**
you can also use perl to print out the USA cities

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
open(NAMES,  "names.txt");
    while (<NAMES>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_ in USA\n" if /_USA$/; # Chicago_USA in USA
    # print "$1 in USA\n" if /(.*)_USA$/; # Chicago in USA
}
close(NAMES);
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same in perl now. I am using regex like

    if ($city =~ m/^(_USA)/){
    print $city;} 
But not getting an output.

Comment: I am not sure how you get `$city` in perl. I have updated my post with a perl code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use grep :

```
grep '_USA$' your_file> new_file
```